# How does `git rebase` skip the commit which its change already has in upstream?

Tags: git, git-rebase

[git-rebase document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) says:

> If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g., because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that commit will be skipped.

But how does Git do that?

Assume any commit `X` is the parent of commit `Y`, and `diffXY` is the result of `git diff X Y` command. And I have following commits:

```
o---o---o        <- master
 \
  o---o---o---o  <- test <- HEAD
```

If I do a `git rebase master`. Then I guess Git does the skipping commit already have in `master` by skipping any commit `Y` in `test` that `diffXY` already have in `master`.

I've ran some examples and they were like what I guessed.

This is just my guess, am I right?

Plus, does Git do this skipping task before Git do the reapplying `test`'s commits onto the `master`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [first versions of `git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a420585f3896c86a8641a0d46483acd2036cb5a3#diff-e76985cd790d625e51082908f0752b45R299) (1.4.4, Oct. 2006) were using [`git format --ignore-if-in-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#git-format-patch---ignore-if-in-upstream)

> This will examine all patches reachable from `<since>` but not from `<until>` and compare them with the patches being generated, and any patch that matches is ignored.

So it was looking at the **[patch ids](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a0cc8aca797dbd7d2be3b67458ff880ed45cddf/Documentation/git-patch-id.txt#L17-L20)**: See [commit 9c6efa3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c6efa366eed0526e82a052b77227451273af0c3) for the [implementation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9c6efa366eed0526e82a052b77227451273af0c3/builtin-log.c#L348-L351).

```
 if (ignore_if_in_upstream &&
    !get_patch_id(commit, &patch_id_opts, sha1) &&
     lookup_object(sha1))
     continue;
```

> A "patch ID" is nothing but a sum of SHA-1 of the file diffs associated with a
> patch, with whitespace and line numbers ignored.
> As such, it's "reasonably stable", but at the same time also reasonably unique, i.e., two patches that have the same "patch ID" are almost guaranteed to be the same thing.

That was later [delegated to `git rebase-am`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46df82d5fa0f83d3c1108ad70248877d6d9b56bb) (Git 1.7.6, Feb. 2011)

And [commit b6266dc, Git 2.1.0, Jul. 2014](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6266dc88b1fcc91d084cc9c65e0b0805cf59d55) used  `--cherry-pick` instead of `--ignore-if-in-upstream`

> When using `git format-patch --ignore-if-in-upstream` we are only allowed to give a single revision range.
> In the next commit we will want to add an additional exclusion revision in order to handle fork points correctly, so convert `git-rebase--am` to use a symmetric
> difference with `--cherry-pick --right-only`.

([Further improved in Git 2.18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da27a6fbd50861149b32cfd1f9e5c36a935c575a#diff-e76985cd790d625e51082908f0752b45R299))

That does not change the "skip identical commit" mechanism.

---

As explained above, "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c083b7619f171d32df633ca0281653afabd788f/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> by default skips changes that are equivalent to commits that are already in the history the branch is rebased onto;

But with Git 2.34, this is now clearer, as it gives messages when this happens to let the users be aware of skipped commits, and also teach them how to tell "rebase" to keep duplicated changes.

See [commit 767a4ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499) (30 Aug 2021) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c083b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c083b7619f171d32df633ca0281653afabd788f), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499): advise if skipping cherry-picked commit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> Silently skipping commits when rebasing with `--no-reapply-cherry-picks` (currently the default behavior) can cause user confusion.
> Issue warnings when this happens, as well as advice on how to preserve the skipped commits.
>
> These warnings and advice are displayed only when using the (default) "merge" rebase backend.
>
> Update the [`git-rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> docs to mention the warnings and advice.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L47-L49):

> ### `skippedCherryPicks`
>
> Shown when [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) skips a commit that has already
> been cherry-picked onto the upstream branch.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L82-L85):

> will be skipped and warnings will be issued (if the `merge` backend is used).
> For example, running `git rebase master` on the following
> history (in which `A'` and `A` introduce the same set of changes, but have different committer information):

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L316-L319):

> When using the `merge` backend, warnings will be issued for each dropped commit (unless `--quiet` is given).
> Advice will also be issued unless `advice.skippedCherryPicks` is set to false (see [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).

So you will now see:

```
skipped previously applied commit xxx
use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
```

Answer (score 8):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789919/1256452) gives the history.  The *mechanism* is what Git calls a *patch ID*.  Git's patch ID concept is documented (albeit a bit lightly) in [the `git patch-id` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html), summarizing it this way:

> ... you can use this thing to look for likely duplicate commits.

This is what `git rev-list --cherry-mark` (with the symmetric difference `...` notation) and `git format-patch --ignore-if-in-upstream` (with a simple exclusion `..` operation) do to detect duplicate commits.  If a commit, whose hash is by definition different from the commit to—at least potentially—be copied, has the same *patch ID* as the commit to be copied, Git assumes that the commit is already copied and therefore there is no need to copy it.

You also asked:

> Plus, does Git do this skipping task before Git do the reapplying `test`'s commits onto the `master`?

Yes: the list of commits to be copied is generated first—during which the patch-ID-equivalent commits are discarded, along with *all* merge commits unless you are using the `-p` or `-r` options—and then the rebase process begins.

(If you use a non-automated `git rebase` that uses `git am`, the rebase process still uses `git format-patch` output as input to `git am`.  Otherwise the commit hashes to be copied are stored in a file, or in the sequencer which may or may not store them in a file, and then the commits are cherry-picked, either by running `git cherry-pick` or directly by the sequencer.  The details depend on your particular Git vintage.)

Comment: I knew you were about to comment. +1. Your man page comes from Git 0.99.6 (Aug. 2005): https://github.com/git/git/commit/52a22d1e726f91b0ba4ea0afb7cfbfaaf624127b. Initally used by cherry and format-patch: https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d23e133d23bc9e26d6f23a4d136901e18e6ffba