# duplicated commits might because rebase from multiple sources

Tags: git

In order to develop a feature, I created a feature branch (called `feature/a`).

During development of `feature/a`, I found there is a existing bug, so I create a bug branch (called `fix/b`) based from master.

After fixed this bug and committed, I checked out `feature/a` again, and ran `git rebase origin/master`. But because it depends on `fix/b`, so I ran `git rebase origin/fix/b`. During both rebasing, I fixed some conflicts.

Then I kept working on `feature/a`, after I finished `feature/a`, just before I request pull request, I realised there were many duplicated commits. Why there are many commits duplicated? I thought it might because it is because I rebased from mixed sources, but I tried to reproduce locally but not happening.

Another questions, In this case, what is the right strategy? Anyone have some thoughts?

---

Update #1

Sorry I forgot to mention, at that moment `fix/b` still didn't merge back to `master` yet. So the situation is more like the below:

```
master --> m1 --> m2
 |\
 | \
 |  feature/a --> a1 --> a2
 |
fix/b --> b1 --> b2
```

Supposing I was at `a2` on `feature/a`, Ideally I expected the following will happen:
* `git rebase master`, and the diagram should become:
--> m1 --> m2 --> a1 --> a2
* `git rebase fix/b`, and the diagram should become:
--> m1 --> m2 --> b1 --> b2 --> a1 --> a2

However, in my case the diagram is more like the below:
--> m1 --> m2 --> b1 --> b2 --> m1 --> m2 --> b1 --> b2 --> a1 --> a2

I couldn't reproduce in my local git repository.

My question actually is: if there are two branches (A and B), both didn't merged to `master`, and one depend on the other (`branch A` depends on `branch B`). In this case, to keep developing `branch A`, should I rebase from `master` and `branch B`?

Comment: You should _not_ have run `git rebase origin/fix/b`.  Assuming you did in fact commit your bug fix directly to `master`, then `git rebase origin/master` should have brought that bug fix into `feature/a`.  This is the source of your problem, I think.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, after I fixed `fix/b`, I request pull request, but it take time to merge back to master, meaning at this moment, `fix/b` didn't merge back to `master` yet.

Comment: That doesn't really change my comment much.  You should not have rebased twice I think.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do rebasing, there are new commits created in the target branch(`feature/a`), from the rebasing branches (`origin/master`) & (`origin/fix/b`). As `origin/master` is already having `origin/fix/b` commits, you are seeing duplicate commits in your target branch `feature/a`, when you rebase from `origin/master`.

What you should have done is, you should have considered `origin/master` as the shared branch for all your merging/rebasing. So, after merging `fix/b` to `origin/master`, you should have just rebased `origin/master` to target branch `feature/a`.

If you want to preserve history, you should go for merge. If you want cleaner history go for rebase. Either case, you should just keep `origin/master` as the shared branch and `rebase/merge` from `origin/master` into your branch. here, it is `feature/a`.

```
git checkout feature/a
git merge origin/master #if you are fond of merge, to keep history accurately
git rebase origin/master #if you are fond of rebase, to keep history cleaner
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. Actually I just realised I didn't mention that `fix/b` didn't merge back to `master` yet. I updated my question, could you have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at your rebase sequence, because similar commits are not supposed to be rebased twice, considering the [patch id mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789919/6309).
Meaning, you shouldn't see m1/m2 repeated twice. And yet, you see them.

> Supposing I was at `a2` on `feature/a`, Ideally I expected the following will happen:  `git rebase master`, and the diagram should become

```
     (master)
 m1 --> m2 --> a1' --> a2' (feature/a)
   \
     -> b1 --> b2 (fix/b)
```

> `git rebase fix/b`, and the diagram should become:
>
> ```
> m1 --> m2 --> b1 --> b2 --> a1 --> a2
> ```

Well... no: you are replaying feature/a (which now include `master` commits) on top of `fix/b`, but `master` still exists.

```
 m1 --> m2 (master)
   \
     -> b1 --> b2 --> m1' --> m2' --> a1'' --> a2'' (feature/a)
```

Hence the repetition of `m1`/`m2`.

Generally, commits from `master` should not be rebased.

Simply merging `fix/b` to `feature/a` is best to quickly go on developing on feature/a while benefiting from `fix/b`.

```
     (master)
 m1 --> m2 --> a1' --> a2' --> M (feature/a)
   \                          /
     -> b1 ----------------> b2 (fix/b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929369/how-to-rebase-local-branch-with-remote-master) explains very well.

Basically, the last step push, we should `git push --force-with-lease`. If we do `git push`, it will generate duplicated commits.